# kubectl logs -f gets "Authorization error"

Tags: kubernetes, authorization, amazon-eks

I recently created a cluster on EKS with eksctl. `kubectl logs -f mypod-0` bumps into Authorization error:

`Error from server (InternalError): Internal error occurred: Authorization error (user=kube-apiserver-kubelet-client, verb=get, resource=nodes, subresource=proxy)`

Any advice and insight is appreciated

Answer (score 9):

You would need to create a ClusterRoleBinding with a Role pointing towards the user : kube-apiserver-kubelet-client

```
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: kubelet-api-admin
subjects:
- kind: User
  name: kube-apiserver-kubelet-client
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: system:kubelet-api-admin
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

kubelet-api-admin is usually a role that has the necessary permissions, but you can replace this with an apt role.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you mean by creating a role? Perhaps include a link to the kubernetes command, or include some example commands, or what file includes the information you have

Answer (score 1):

On a prem cluster, I had an issue where I changed the DNS address of the master. You will need to change the dns name in the `/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf` on each node then `sudo systemctl restart kublet.service.`

Answer (score 1):

I could solve this issue by editing the `aws-auth` configmap. I added the clusterrole `system:node` in the worker role.

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  mapRoles: |
    - rolearn: 'WORKER ROLE'
      username: 'NAME'
      groups:
        - ...
        - system:nodes
```

Answer (score 0):

This may happen if your aws-auth config map is broken / empty. And it may happen if, for example, you run multiple eksctl operations in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this error in my AWS EKS cluster when the DNS servers configured in the DHCP Options Set for the VPC containing the EKS cluster became unreachable. When DNS is unreachable the authorization requests fail to access the authorization source.